# Any formula for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{(kt)^m}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analysis

I wonder if there is a formula for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{k^mt^m}$ or non-trivial estimate, where we may assume $t=o(1)$ and $m\ge 2$ is a positive integer?

Comment: What sort of bound are you hoping for?  This sum tends to be a bounded by a small interval (e.g. $[1,3]$) times the largest term in the sum, either the first or last term.

Comment: @EricTowers Is there an explicit formula for it, like $\sum k^m$? If not, any non-trivial bound, for example $n e^{n^mt^m}$ is welcome.

Comment: Suggestion: perhaps notate this as $$F(n,m)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\exp\left( k^mt^m\right)$$ That strikes me as a touch more reader-friendly

Answer (score 2):

It's easiest to break this into cases depending on whether $t$ is positive, zero, or negative and, if negative, whether $|t| \in (0,1)$ or $|t| > 1$, and also whether $m$ is even or odd.

- $t < 0$, $|t| \geq 1$, $m$ odd : The summands decrease superexponentially, dominated by the first term.  The sum is in $[1,3)$.  (We could tighten the upper bound to $2 + \mathrm{e}^{-7}$ easily, but this seems excessive.)
- $t < 0$, $|t| < 1$, $m$ odd : Lower bounded by the first term, $1$, upper bounded by $n+1$.
- $t < 0$ and $m$ is even.  Same as $t > 0$, below.
- $t = 0$ : The sum is $n+1$.
- <strike>$t > 0$ : The terms grow superexponentially.  The sum is dominated by its last term and is $C \mathrm{e}^{(n t)^m}$ for some $C \in [1,2]$.</strike>

---

Regarding the question in comments about the last case.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n \mathrm{e}^{(kt)^m}
    &= \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} \mathrm{e}^{(kt)^m-(nt)^m}\right) \mathrm{e}^{(nt)^m}  \\
    &= \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} \mathrm{e}^{-(n^m - k^m)t^m}\right) \mathrm{e}^{(nt)^m}
\end{align*}

I should have believed me when I said the relative magnitudes of $t$ and $1$ matter.

- $t > 0$, $|t| < 1$: The $k=n$ term in the parentheses above gives a lower bound of $\mathrm{e}^{(nt)^m}$.  Every term in the parenthesized sum is bounded between $0$ and $1$, so your sum is bounded by $(n+1)\mathrm{e}^{(nt)^m}$.
- $t > 0$, $|t| \geq 1$: The sum in parentheses is \begin{align*}  
  &\left( 1 + \left( \mathrm{e}^{-t^m} \right)^{n^m - (n-1)^m} + \left( \mathrm{e}^{-t^m} \right)^{n^m - (n-2)^m} + \cdots + \left( \mathrm{e}^{-t^m} \right)^{n^m - 0} \right) \\ 
  &\qquad < \left( 1 + \left( \mathrm{e}^{-t^m} \right) + \left( \mathrm{e}^{-t^m} \right)^2 + \cdots + \left( \mathrm{e}^{-t^m} \right)^n \right)  \\
  &\qquad < \frac{1}{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t^m}}  \\
  &\qquad = 1 + \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t^m}}{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-t^m}}  \\
  &\qquad \in \left[1,\frac{\mathrm{e}}{\mathrm{e}-1} \right]  \\
  &\qquad \subset [1,2]  \text{.}
  \end{align*}  Your sum is $C \mathrm{e}^{(n t)^m}$ for some $C \in [1,2]$.

Comment: For the last case, why $C\in [1,2]$? I have a feeling that it is true. While I wonder if there is a proof?

Comment: @Connor : I think I've clarified what's going on in the $t>0$ case(s).  Is there more to say?

Comment: Is there a better bound for $0<t<1$ case?

Comment: @Connor : Better in what sense?

Comment: For example, when $m=1$, then the constant ahead of main term can get rid of $n$ by formula of sum of geometric series. I wonder if there is an upper bound gets rid of $n$?

Comment: @Connor : $m$ is required $\geq 2$.

Comment: Yes, so I wonder if $nt\ll 1$, is it possible to bound the sum by a constant $C$ not involving $n$, times $(e^{nt})^m$?

Comment: @Connor : No.  At $t=0$, the value of the sum is $n+1$.  When $t$ is barely greater than zero, the sum is of $n+1$ numbers exceptionally close to $1$.  The transition from sum of things close to $1$ to sum of things majorized by a geometric series happens for some $t \in (0,1)$ and is certainly finished once $t=1$.  But prior to that, we cannot avoid counting the summands, i.e., cannot avoid a simple $n$-dependence.

Comment: @Connor : Also, $(\mathrm{e}^{nt})^m = \mathrm{e}^{mnt}$, which is not what we want.